# How to stop creepypasta.wikia from suddenly redirecting me on Android basic browser?

Tags: browser

For the past few days I've been reading the creepypasta.wikia site on my new, virus-free Android phone. For the past couple of days when I'm reading a story, not clicking anything at all, the page changes to another page saying that I need to update Android at the Google store, or one of two other adverts I can't recall exactly. The page I'm on changes, this isn't a pop up or under so if I want to return to the creepypasta I was reading I have to click Back. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is called [malvertising](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malvertising). As an user, your only option is to use an ad blocker like AdAway.